# how to chage MDIconbutton color

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Can somebody help me change te color of my MDIconButton.
This is my code.

```
             MDIconButton:

                icon: "account"
                pos_hint:{"center_x": .95, "center_y": .95}
                user_font_size: "35sp"
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
```

I know it would be a simple problem but i am a starter

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/components/button/index.html#mdiconbutton), you can use `text_color`:

```
theme_text_color: "Custom"
text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
```